# Delegate between Java and C#

Tags: c#, java, ikvm

I'm really new to c# and am running into a slight problem.
I've got a java library which provides alot of functionality i need (and sadly with no c# equivalent).
I came across IKVM and thought that might be what i need.

I can make a DLL from a Java class, no problem there. 
But what i really need is the DLL to callback to a c# class in the case of some event.
I have searched a bit and found another question on here that handles the same problem (and even gives an answer). The problem is, the answer is not complete.

Have a look at the other question and the answer here:
[IKVM C# to Java Interop with Callback using IKVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145208/ikvm-c-sharp-to-java-interop-with-callback-using-ikvm)

So far i understand the author uses a self made library to handle the callback via a delegate. But i really can't figure out what's in that library, as the contents of that are not listed in the answer.

Can anyone help me out on that maybe?

Comment: After converting a Java library to c# using IKVM, output is completely c# library. There is no more java there(only classes that *taste* like java). So I don't get what you are trying to do.

Comment: Wow, i missunderstood the usage of IKVM completely. I thought it'd allow you to only call methods on classes in the DLL, rather than actually completely porting it to a c# library. All is fine now, i made the DLL and used it to recreate a test program (which was previously made in Java) and it works like a charm!